# WP REST API - reading custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-api

I have a WP site that runs on WP version 4.3 and using a plugin WP REST API version2-beta9. I have a custom post type **animals** which has an ACF select field of **class** which has values like mammals, reptile, etc.

If getting values of custom post types is available for WP REST API, is it possible that I can **GET** request on my endpoint to retrieve values of all **mammals** under the **animals** custom post type? If yes, how do I do that?

Comment: Are you using the REST API plugin or the one that's bundled into WP version 4.4? If the plugin, what version?

Comment: WP version 4.3 and using a plugin WP REST API version2-beta9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked the WP REST API documentation for the version2-beta9, it is not yet implemented so I guess I have to code my own plugin to work around on it.